# How to get response status code from APIs in JS?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, response

I am making an API call to login via Ajax. In case the Api is not successful then in error function I need to get status code that Api returned.

```
            var weblink = "https://" + domain + username;
            
            $j.ajax({
            url: weblink,
            data: "", 
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "xml",
            beforeSend: function(request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedData);
            },
            
            crossDomain: true,
            
            success: function(result) {
            
            console.log(result);
            
            },
            
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {   
                
                console.log("Status: " + jqXHR.statusCode);
                
            }
           });
```

But I am unable to get status code, do I need to parse it or what?

Answer (score 0):

Made **dataType:'JSON',**

and apply this code:

```
success:function(res){
    console.log(res)
},
error:function(e){
    console.log(e)
},
complete:function(c){
    console.log(c)
}
```

Comment: dataType:'xml' is a requirement for Api.

Comment: Did you check, what you will get in the console?